# Example of a Levy measure with infinite mass around zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, levy-processes

A measure $\nu$ is a  Levy measure if:
\begin{equation}
    \nu(\{0\}),\quad \int_{|x|<1}|x|^{2} \nu (dx) <\infty, \quad \int_{|x| \geq 1}  \nu (dx)<\infty. 
\end{equation}
At first, I thought that necessarily for $\epsilon >0$:

\begin{equation}\label{prefinite_condition_measure0}\tag{I}
    \nu( (-\epsilon, \epsilon) ) = \infty  
\end{equation}

But this is not true.

For example, by the Levy-Khintchine representation of infinitely divisible distributions $X$ , we have that $X\sim (b, \sigma, \nu)$, where $\nu$ is a Levy measure. If $X$ is a [Compound Poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), $X \sim CP(\lambda, dF)$
$$X = \sum_{j=1}^N Z_j, \quad N \sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda), \quad Z \sim dF$$
we have that $X \sim (0,0, \lambda dF)$. So, certainly we have $d\nu = \lambda dF$ with:

$$\nu( (-\epsilon, \epsilon) ) < \infty, \quad \epsilon < 1 .$$

So I am looking for some example of Levy measure that satisfy  (\ref{prefinite_condition_measure0}).

**Could you give me some example?**

(We certainly cannot build on an example coming from a Compound Poisson distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\nu (x)=\frac 1 {x^{\alpha}} \chi_{(0,\infty)}dx$ with $ 1<\alpha <3$ is such an example.

Comment: This seems to be ok. I will check the properties and accept the answer. Just one more question: is my last sentence correct? There is no chance of getting a Levy measure from a Compound Poisson distribution. Am I right? (Sorry for my ignorance about measurement theory)

Comment: @PSE Yes, you are right about Compound Poisson Levy measures.