# Example of a Levy measure with infinite mass around zero but with finite second moment

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, levy-processes

Let $X$ be an infinitely divisible random variable with the  "Lévy–Khintchine triplet" $(a,\sigma, \nu)$ representation where $d\nu (x)=\frac 1 {x^{\alpha}} \chi_{(0,\infty)}dx$ with $ 1<\alpha <3$. This measure is a Levy measure, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
    \nu(\{0\}),\quad \int_{|x|<1}|x|^{2} \nu (dx) <\infty, \quad \int_{|x| \geq 1}  \nu (dx)<\infty. 
\end{equation}

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561024/example-of-a-levy-measure-with-infinite-mass-around-zero/4561025#4561025), we have inifnite mass around zero:
\begin{equation}\label{prefinite_condition_measure0}\tag{I}
    \nu( (-\epsilon, \epsilon) ) = \infty , \quad 0<\epsilon < 1. 
\end{equation}
Note that for $\alpha = 2+ r$, with $-1<r<1$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2 d\nu(x)= \int_{\mathbb R} x^2 \frac 1 {x^{2+r}} \chi_{(0,\infty)}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-r}  dx = \infty
\end{aligned}

So I am looking for some example of Levy measure $\nu$ that satisfy  (\ref{prefinite_condition_measure0}) but at the same time, I want:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2 d\nu(x) < \infty$$
**Could you give me some example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $d\nu (x)=\chi_{(0,1)} (x) \frac 1 {x^{\alpha}}$ where $1 <\alpha <3$.